# ASP.NET MVC SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqlexception

The `Job` model class has a column:

```
public DateTime JobDate { get; set; }
```

When I am trying to add a new `Job`, the input of `JobDate` is from

```
<input type="dateTime" name="JobDate" />
```

I get this error:

> SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

How can I fix it?

Comment: What value are you trying to save when you get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue. One solution I came across was to make the DateTime column nullable by adding a "?" to the model:

```
public DateTime? JobDate { get; set; }
```